# Create an object from its name without eval

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, this

I need to create an object from its name in Node.js. How can I do it (without using eval)?

For example, I've tried something like the code bellow, but it failed on `Person is unknown'.
I guess it has something with the context (this). I tried the bind/call/apply functions, but with no avail.

```
module.export = {
    class Person =  {/*....*/};

    var createObject = function(name) {
        return Function('return new ' + name + '();')();
    };

    const p1 = new Person(); // works
    const p2 = eval('return new Person();'); // works, but has security issues
    const p3 = createObject('Person'): // doesn't work.

}:
```

I’d appreciate it if you could show me how to write the createObject function right.

Comment: What's the purpose of something like this?

Comment: I need to create objects from configuration file.

Comment: what is the real use case for this?

Comment: Again, create objects from configuration file or dynamic object creation

Comment: My guess would be that the stuff that you're passing into `Function` is being run in an isolated context.

Comment: What's wrong with `switch`? It's not as though you will get some unknown object type from the config file.

Comment: From a security perspective, how is `eval` any worse/different than `Function(...)()` ?

Comment: what is the use of `new Foo` or in an other case of `new Bar`, if both required an assignment of the instance?

Comment: I don't want to add objects I define to the switch...

Comment: Now I must join all the other responders and ask, why? What use case are you talking about that makes `switch` problematic? Is it just a personal preference, or is there a technical reason you don't want to add objects to a `switch`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: switch isn't generic and someone can forget to add an object there

Comment: Someone could forget to add an object? You would have the same problem with `eval`. You can't create an object from "Person()" if you haven't already written the code to create a `Person`.

Comment: Your code is already not generic, because you have to write the specific class anyway. And if you're worried that someone would forget to add an object to the `switch` itself, well, that's what unit testing is for. Write your test to try all possible inputs.

Comment: Related (maybe even dupe?): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript

Comment: It appears that it's not worth trying to answer this question because every single answer is immediately downvoted, even perfectly acceptable answers.  Something is either busted on stack overflow or there's a nefarious and silent user out there trying to punish anyone who attempts to help.  Not sure what's going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a map of names to constructors:

```
const permittedTypes = new Map([
    ['Person', Person],
    …
]);

const configuredType = 'Person';

const p1 = new (permittedTypes.get(configuredType));
```

Comment: May want to test for an unsupported name being passed in.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you create a map of creatable objects and lookup against it?

i.e.:

```
const creatableObjects = {
  'Person': Person,
  'SomethingElse': SomethingElse
}
const config = getConfig();
const createdObject = new (creatableObjects[config.objectName])();
```

Comment: shout out to Ryan for fixing my grammatical errors. And shout out to all the other correct answers that got downvoted for who knows what reason. I wasn't even the first answer haha

Answer (score 0):

The stuff that you pass into `Function` doesn't get access to variables defined in the scope from where the constructor is called.

See the [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).

> Functions created with the Function constructor do not create closures to their creation contexts; they always are created in the global scope. When running them, they will only be able to access their own local variables and global ones, not the ones from the scope in which the Function constructor was called. This is different from using eval with code for a function expression.

Though I'd be curious to know what your use case is. (I suppose my answer doesn't properly answer your question. It just explains why you're getting an error)

Answer (score 0):

Arbitrarily accessing variables using `eval()` or `new Function()` can lead to security issues, and isn't all that reliable either when the problem of scoping comes into question.

What you can do instead is use an object with keys mapping to different classes, then reference the object using the specific key you want, so something like this:

```
const classes = {
  Person: class Person {/* ... */},
  Dog: class Dog {/* ... */},
  Cat: class Cat {/* ... */},
}

function createObject(className) {
  return new classes[className]()
}

const p = createObject('Person') // returns a person
```

One of the comments also suggested a switch statement, which would work as well. Whatever's cleaner.

Comment: This seems like a prefectly reasonable solution (similar to the answer I provided).  We need to provide some upvotes here to cancel out the serial downvoters.